# Exponential type of a product of entire functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{b_m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ be two sequences of points in $\mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z}{a_n}\right)\quad\mbox{and}\quad g(z)=\prod_{m=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z}{b_m}\right)
$$
are entire functions of finite exponential types $0<A_f<\infty$ and $0<A_g<\infty$ (growth orders are $\rho_f=\rho_g=1$), respectively. Is it true that the exponential type $A_{fg}$ of the entire function $f(z)g(z)$ satisfies
$$
\max\{A_f,A_g\}<A_{fg}
$$
(strict inequality)?

More generally, given that the growth of $f$ as above is $\rho_f=1$, is there a way to establish the exponential type from the sequence $\{a_n\}$?

Thank you.

I expected this to be a university-level question, so I posted it on MSE ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016243/exponential-type-of-a-product-of-entire-functions)). But it doesn't seem to even get any attention. So I am posting it here. Apologies if it sounds too elementary to some; I am not a specialist in complex analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the first question: Your inequality is incorrect for exponential type functions. Take $f(z)=e^z,\; g(z)=e^{-z}$, both have exponential type 1. These examples are of course not of the form of infinite product that you request.

But if $f$ is defined by an infinite product as you wrote, then (with usual understanding of an infinite product) the condition of convergence is
$$\sum\frac{1}{|a_n|}<\infty,$$
and this implies that your functions are of exponential type $0$. (Levin, Ch. I, section 4, Lemma 3).
Then $A_f=A_g=A_{fg}=0$, so your strict inequality is wrong and the non-strict inequality holds trivially.

In general, for functions of exponential type it is true that $A_{fg}\leq A_f+A_g$, and
equality can hold.

On your second question. To tell the exponential type of the infinite product from its zeros is possible (but not simple in general). Let $n(r)$ be the counting function of zeros. For functions of exponential type, $n(r)/r$ has finite upper limit as $r\to\infty$. 
This is a consequence of Jensen's formula. But this upper limit is not simply related to the exponential type: the arguments of zeros also have a strong influence.

Simple relations can be obtained only in the (important) special cases, for example when the zeros are real, and limits $\lim n^+(r)/r$ and
$\lim n^-(r)/r$ exist, where $n_{\pm}$ counts the number of positive and negative zeros.

For the details, see B. Levin, Distribution of zeros of entire functions, AMS, 1970.

EDIT. @Christian Remling suggested to use the following definition of the class of sequences:
$$f(z)=\lim_{r\to\infty}\sum_{|a_n|\leq r}\left(1-\frac{z}{a_n}\right)$$
converges. Here is an example with $\max\{A_f,A_g\}>A_{fg}$ in this class.
I use the facts and notation from Levin's book, English edition.
Define $a_{2k}=k,\; a_{2k+1}=-k^2/(k+b),$ where $b>0$ is a constant to be chosen. Then define a canonical product of genus $1$:
$$F(z)=\prod_n\left(1-\frac{z}{a_n}\right)e^{\displaystyle z/a_n}.$$
To this function, Theorem 2 from section 1, Chapter II can be applied. In the notation of this section, we have $\tau_F=0$, and $d\Delta$ has two atoms of mass $1$: one at $0$ another at $\pi$. Then formula (2.06) gives
$$H_F(\theta)=\pi\sin|\theta|.$$
It is not surprising, of course that $F$ behaves like $\sin\pi z$, and this
can be proved by direct estimation, without a reference to Levin's book.

On the other hand, the product $f$ is conditionally convergent, so exponents
in the product of $F$ can be taken out, and we obtain
$$F(z)=f(z)\exp(-\pi^2b z/6).$$
Therefore
$$H_f(\theta)=\pi\sin|\theta|+\frac{\pi^2b}{6}\cos\theta.$$
Now it is clear that when $b$ is very large, the function $f$ behaves like an exponential, and we will have a counterexample with $g(z)=f(-z)$.

To be specific, take $b=7$. Then $A_f=\max_{\theta}H_f(\theta)> 3.5\pi.$ Take $g(z)=f(ze^{-3.4i})$ and we obtain
$$A_{fg}=\max_\theta\left(H_f(\theta)+H_f(\theta-3.4)\right)<1.5\pi,$$
where I used Maple to plot trigonometric functions and read their maxima from display.

Notice: In the Russian edition of Levin, formula (2.06) is printed with a misprint.

Comment: If it is easy to construct counterexamples, would you, please, do me a favour and construct one for me? Thank you. Of course, I had exponenrials in mind when posting this question. But for Weierstrass products as above, the product has twice as many zeros (multiplicity counted), and this might force a faster growth at a first glance.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely have a look into Levin's book, but I may still not be able to conclude without a specialist's help. Hence the enquiry.

Comment: @Bedovlat: Your question makes little sense, as stated, because the exponential type of your infinite products is always $0$, if the products are understood in the usual way. See my edited answer.

Comment: Wow! What about the Weierstrass factorization of $\sin(\pi z)/(\pi z)$?

Comment: $$\sin\pi z=\pi z\prod_{n\neq 0}\left(1-z/n\right)e^{z/n}=\pi z\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-z^2/n^2\right)$$ are not of the kind you wrote!

Comment: What if I order the set of zeros as ${1,-1,2,-2,\ldots}$? Then even partial sums converge but odds don't? Is that convergence criterion really THAT sensitive?

Comment: You can order any way you want, but then you have to use the first product I wrote. It has an exponential factor, you see? Extended comments are discouraged on this site, but you can address your questions by e-mail if you wish.

Comment: That's an excellent offer, thank you. I've been looking for a specialist in function theory for a while. Will write you soon.

Comment: Christian, that was my intuition as well. But Alexandre seems to claim that such infinite products are not legitimate. At least superficially it seems that if $\sum_{n}\frac1{a_n}<\infty$ in a certain order than the exponential factors in Alexandre's Hadamard factorization can be taken out of the product or so.. I am confused.

Comment: @Bedovlat: Actually, I misquoted Lindelof's theorem when quoting from memory, it really says that the partial sums $\sum 1/a_n$ are bounded, in the natural ordering, and we need a little more than that. But you could just make that assumption by hand, that $\sum 1/a_n$ converges conditionally and then use this to define the Hadamard product. For example it would work in the $f(z)=\sin z$ example.

Comment: @Christian Remling: If "converges conditionally" means $\lim_{r\to\infty}\prod_{|a_k|\leq r}$ then one can construct examples with $\max\{ A_fA_g\}>A_{fg}$. But I want the class of functions to be described precisely, before I spend time on describing counterexamples.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I believe this second version (conditional convergence) must be what the OP had in mind because, as you point out, if one insists on absolute convergence (as one normally would, by introducing the convergence generating exponentials), then the question disappears.

Comment: @Christian Remling: I inserted a counterexample with your definition of conditional convergence.

Comment: The statement $A_f \approx 3.4$ is not correct. The code and plot on demand.

Comment: @user64494: thanks. I corrected the numbers.